# Invalid characters in Merged ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, resharper, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I have the following resource dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
       <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Asi.Ui.CustomControls;component/Themes/ExpanderItem.xaml" />
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

I get a Resharper 7.1.3 error on "application:,,," reporting "Invalid characters in path".

From what I understand this is the correct syntax of the merged dictionary. Did I do something wrong with the syntax? If the syntax is correct why am I getting this error?

The code compiles and seems to run fine, but I'm not sure if this will come back to bite me later.

Comment: Try closing the designer and opening it again... or rebuilding your solution...

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Did a clean, closed VS, and rebuild. No luck.

Comment: What's your build action for those resource dictionaries? Page?

Comment: It is used by App.xaml so it is an Application

Comment: This is from MSDN pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;component/Subfolder/ResourceFile.xaml and yours looks the same so dont worry :)

Comment: I guess I will hope for the best then.

Comment: Just an update that it never caused any issues.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem when I added a reference to "System.Windows" into the referenced xaml assembly, which in your case is Asi.Ui.CustomControls. Removing this reference fixed the error.

Although the application built and ran successfully with the reported issue, it had the annoying side effect that the intellisense stopped working when editting the dictionary source path.

Comment: I found the same problem when merging a dictionary from another project, just like the OP. Funnily enough, I solved the issue by removing the reference to System.Windows (instead of the one where the .xaml was in). Thanks for this post. It saved me a lot of headache :)